# False Logic how can i fixed

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGPBb.png)]
As you see i already set my logic if price are higher than sma40 will show 1.
But you can see I added the sma40 to double chek and found that it all the price beneath with sma40.

It's not appear true value that could be 0 , How can i do?

Comment: Please share the 2 codes, without it is hard to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ta.sma()` will return the simple moving average (MA or SMA).

What you have on your chart is smoothed moving average (SMMA). Those two are different.

In the below image, SMMA is the red line and MA is the green line. As you can see, the price is above the MA (hence you are getting `1`) but below the SMMA.

[image]